# Can't get the value of regex Match in a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a form with a Listbox, in this Listbox i have datas from a .xml file.

When i select an input i get the value of this input in a var string with :

```
string s = lstCust.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

It gives me : "John Doe, JohnDoe@stack.io phone:00336598745"

Now i would like to get only the mail address so I'm trying it with this Regex :

```
@"([A-Za-z0-9._ % -] +@[A-Za-z0-9.-] +\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})*"
```

With this method :

```
string mail = Regex.Match(s, @"([A-Za-z0-9._ % -] +@[A-Za-z0-9.-] +\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})*").Value;
```

I'm sure my Regex works because a

```
Regex.Match(s, @"([A-Za-z0-9._ % -] +@[A-Za-z0-9.-] +\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})*").Success.ToString();
```

gives me a `true`.

But the value of my var *mail* is always equals to "" (empty).

Any idea on what am i doing wrong ?

Thx

Comment: Have you tried this on a regex tester? There are plenty of them available. (http://regexstorm.net/tester)

Comment: I suggest using an xml parser. Show us xml file.

Comment: ok I won't try to give you a pattern that will work, because I don't know enough about the variability of your input. But it returns `true` because of the `*` asterisk at the end. It means: "match 0 or more occurences". Basically that is a tautological expression. It will always be true. Unfortunately your pattern is not suited to match the input. You can test my assumption bby changing the `*` to a `+` and force the pattern to match "at least 1 time"! then it will turn to false

Comment: Yes i tested it on regexr.com. Thanks to everyone for solving this "issue" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have spaces in your regex pattern that are preventing it from matching. Remove the spaces and the * at the end

```
string mail = Regex.Match(s, @"([A-Za-z0-9._ % -]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})").Value;
```

[Regex Storm Example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5BA-Za-z0-9._%20%25-%5D%2B%40%5BA-Za-z0-9.-%5D%2B%5C.%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%7B2%2C4%7D&i=John%20Doe%2C%20JohnDoe%40stack.io%20phone%3A00336598745)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below Regex.

```
([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)
```

It will give you the email **JohnDoe@stack.io** from the give string **John Doe, JohnDoe@stack.io phone:00336598745**

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rKcgFc/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Your expression does not actually match. You have a `*` (0 or more occurrences) after your capture group. Because the expression doesn't actually match, it finds 0 occurrences of the expression in the capture group, but because of the `*` this is allowed, thus the matching succeeds.

If there is only one email address in the string you're matching against. remove the * at the end and try to find out why the regex isn't actually working.